# Google Spreadsheets tickbox increment and time-driven reset

Tags: checkbox, google-apps-script, google-sheets, increment

I would like to use tickbox function on spreadsheets; when its ticked at the end of the day defined cell values will increment and tickbox will reset.

```
    function resetCells() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Lordaeron');
var cells = ['B2:B1000']
    .map(function (c) {
        ss.getRange(c)
        .setValue("FALSE");
    });
}
```

This resets checkbox with time trigger I need to add conditional increment. If B columb value is TRUE C columb value will increment in the same row.

Example:

Initial Sheet >>

```
Checkbox |  Value 1 | Value 2 |  
-------------------------------
   X     |     1    |    0    | 
   V     |     2    |    0    |
   X     |     3    |    1    | 
   V     |     1    |    2    | 
   X     |     2    |    3    |
```

One day later [Desired Result] >>

```
Checkbox |  Value 1 | Value 2 |  
-------------------------------
   X     |     1    |    0    | 
   X     |     3    |    1    |
   X     |     3    |    1    | 
   X     |     2    |    3    | 
   X     |     2    |    3    |
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1khPC5r2p0b1srsEGka3fl-GAl6nHACaVR0Cf31cqA1o/edit?usp=sharing here is example base sheet.

Thanks in advance

==============================================

Additinally I asked for how to add upper limit as 100 to not to reach certain number.
Thanks to Tanaike I fixed issue by this code snippet:

```
function resetDaily() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet');
  var range = ss.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, ss.getLastRow() - 1);
  var values = range.getValues().map(function(e) {
    if (Number(e[8]) <= 94) {
    return e[0] ? [false, e[1], Number(e[2]) + 6, Number(e[3]) + 1] : e;
    } else {
      return e[0] ? [false, e[1], 100, Number(e[3]) + 1] : e;
    }
  }); 
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you? You'll need [tag:google-apps-script]. Start and post your code.

Comment: In your script, it seems that you try to retrieve the values of checkbox from the column B. But in your sample table, it seems that it is put to the column A. If your script is not latest one, please modify it. And in order to understand correctly about your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1khPC5r2p0b1srsEGka3fl-GAl6nHACaVR0Cf31cqA1o/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the simple base for what I am trying to achieve.
If tickbox is checked at the end of the day. Attendance day will increase +1 and Assignment points will increase +6 and tickbox check will reset.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer, because I thought that I could understand your situation from your shared spreadsheet and comment. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstand what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `resetCells()` is installed as the time trigger for doing `If tickbox is checked at the end of the day.`. This is done by yourself.
- When `resetCells()` is run, it checks all checkboxes of column "A".
- If the checkbox of a row is `false`, do nothing for the row.
- If the checkbox of a row is `true`, for the row, it add `+6` to the value of column "C" and add `+1` to the value of column "D". And then, it changes the value of column "A" of the row to `false`.

If my understanding your situation and what you want is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, all values of column "A" change to `false`. But the original values cannot be retrieved. So there are no materials for modifying column "C" and "D".
- Flow of this modified script is as follows.

  1. Retrieve all values of the data range.
  2. Modify the values.
  3. Overwrite the sheet using the modified values.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

```
function resetCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet');
  var range = ss.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, ss.getLastRow() - 1);
  var values = range.getValues().map(function(e) {
    return e[0] ? [false, e[1], Number(e[2]) + 6, Number(e[3]) + 1] : e;
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

#### Note:

- If there are often the situation that all values of column "A" are `false`, I think that the process cost can be reduced by including the script for checking the values of column "A".

### Added:

In this update, the script can change the value as a boundary when the value of column "C" is 100.

```
function resetCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet');
  var range = ss.getDataRange().offset(1, 0, ss.getLastRow() - 1);
  var values = range.getValues().map(function(e) {
    if (Number(e[2]) < 100) { // or <= 100
      return e[0] ? [false, e[1], Number(e[2]) + 6, Number(e[3]) + 1] : e;
    } else {
      // do something
    }
  });
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: This code including everything that I am trying to achieve. Sir, thank you so much for your help and interest. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I noticed lately, is it possible to add upper limit for Assignment points? For example not to pass beyond 100

Comment: @Kutay Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. And about your new question, it is possible to do. So I added the updated script to my answer. Could you please confirm it? I'm not sure about the specification you want. So please replace ``// do something`` to the script you want.

Comment: @Kutay I'm sorry. When you add the script, could you please add it to your question?

Comment: I fixed it. I am sorry, I am not used stackoverflow yet. I have more questions but I think I should create new thread for them. Dear Sir, Thank you once again

Comment: @Kutay Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was solved.